# Generate Missing Bpmn Diagram Elements

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, bpmn

There are bpmn files without diagram elements.
Eclipse Bpmn Plugin can generate them.

**Java solution to generate missing elements is needed.**

Can I somehow reuse eclipse bpmn plugin?

I've downloaded sources, but could not find a way to do that.
Probably there are other frameworks?

I tried to use camunda, downloaded its editor, but it seems it does not support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Studio of [Bonita BPM solution](http://www.bonitasoft.com/how-we-do-it/downloads) to generate automatically the graphical part of a BPMN 2 file.

regards,